# List of all running processes

Tags: c, objective-c, macos

How can I get a list of the names of all currently running processes? (In C/Objective-C on Mac OS X.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cocoa processes can be retrieved from `NSWorkspace`

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications]
```

For the entire process list (i.e. including non graphical) see [Technical Q&A QA1123](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html)

Comment: annoyingly - that link seems to be dead. I can't find the tech note by that number.

Comment: try this: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/qa/qa2001/qa1123.html

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search yielded the following result for me :

http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/a-simple-objectie-c-class-for-checking-if-a-specific-process-is-running/

Notice this goes even further and adds a function to search for a running process.

Answer (score -1):

I know you can do this on unix like systems. In the directory /proc are directories which stand for every process. In those directories you have a file called cmdline which hold the command line who started this process.

I don't know if this is the same on Mac OS X, but you can go further with that.

Comment: /proc is a Linux idiom and not available on OS X.

Comment: jon hohle: Very true, but I think you meant "an **awesome** Linux idiom".